# Changing the state of my parent component from a stateless child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

I want to change the state of my component `PaymentScreen` from a stateless component `OverlayAddAddress`

Inside of the `OverlayAddAddress` I have this :

```
 isOverlayVisible,
 onBackdropPress,
 address,
 city,
 zipCode,
 phoneNumber,
}) => {
 return (
   <Overlay
     overlayBackgroundColor="#f2f2f2"
     isVisible={isOverlayVisible}
     onBackdropPress={onBackdropPress}>
     <TextInput
       style={styles.input}
       placeholder="Adresse"
       onChangeText={address => address}
       value={address}
     />
     <TextInput
       style={styles.input}
       placeholder="Ville"
       onChangeText={city => city}
       value={city}
     />
     <TextInput
       style={styles.input}
       placeholder="Code postal"
       onChangeText={zipCode => zipCode}
       value={zipCode}
     />
     <TextInput
       style={styles.input}
       keyboardType="decimal-pad"
       placeholder="Numéro de téléphone"
       onChangeText={phoneNumber => phoneNumber}
       value={phoneNumber}
     />
     <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonSave}>
       <Text style={styles.buttonSaveText}>Enregister</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   </Overlay>
 )
}
```

And inside the parent component I have this :

```
<OverlayAddAddress
          isOverlayVisible={this.state.overlayAddAdress}
          onBackdropPress={() => this.setState({overlayAddAdress: false})}
          address={this.state.address}
          city={this.state.city}
          zipCode={this.state.zipCode}
          phoneNumber={this.state.phoneNumber}
  />
```

My problem is when is want to change the state from the textInput inside OverlayAddAddress, I can transfer the props from parent to child but I don't how to get back the value for updating the state in the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those situations where you want to update the state of the parent from inside a stateless compnnet, you need to pass a function that updates the state in the parent class

in your case you have the onChange that mutates a prop, which is a copy of the state

```
     <TextInput
       style={styles.input}
       placeholder="Adresse"
       onChangeText={address => address} // this line should be passed from the parent 
       value={address}
     />
```

so the solution is to make the onChangeText a prop so that the parrent passes that function like so,

```js
 <TextInput
       style={styles.input}
       placeholder="Adresse"
       onChangeText={props.onAddressChange}
       value={address}
     />
```

and in the parent component do this

```js
<OverlayAddAddress
          isOverlayVisible={this.state.overlayAddAdress}
          onBackdropPress={() => this.setState({overlayAddAdress: false})}
          address={this.state.address}
          onAddressChange={(value) => setState({address: value})} // will do the trick for you
          city={this.state.city}
          zipCode={this.state.zipCode}
          phoneNumber={this.state.phoneNumber}
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

In PaymentScreen, create a function that changes the desired field. For example:

`const changeText = (text) => { setText(text) }`

Then, pass this function as props to OverlayAddAddress. Then, use it inside your OverlayAddAddress component to change the parent value. For example:

```
<TextInput
   style={styles.input}
   keyboardType="decimal-pad"
   placeholder="Numéro de téléphone"
   onChangeText={phoneNumber => setText(phoneNumber)}
   value={phoneNumber}
 />
```